# Excel COUNTIFS with NETWORKDAYS between a column and a date, excluding holidays

Tags: excel-formula, countif

I have a table with one column containing start dates. How can I get the weekly count of the no. of rows/records which are older than 15 days by weekend, for every week. This should be excluding weekends and holidays? Please see attached image for reference. [image: Image of Sample data and expected Output]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the expected result will include all dates older than the weekend on the current row for that city, you can use NetWorkdays nested in a Sumproduct.

In the screenshot, the formula is

```
=SUMPRODUCT(--(NETWORKDAYS($B$2:$B$14+0,$F3)-1>15),--($D$2:$D$14=G$2))
```

[image]

Comment: That would work. But I have more than a year's worth of data, so I would have to add too many columns. Is there any other way to handle this without addition of columns?

Comment: Your date is in one column. How is that a problem? Why would there be too many columns? You only need one extra column to calculate the NetWorkdays.

Comment: I would need to check the networkdays for each weekend date. For e.g. networkdays between start date and 2 Jun would be one column and then another column for 9 Jun etc. And then I would have to count the rows which are >15 for each week separately from these columns... right?

Comment: Can you fill in your sample table and show the expected result? I'm not sure what you want to achieve. i.e. what does 14-Jul show for these places? All the events already included in the rows above?

Comment: I added a formula to my answer